# Hide Http(s) traffic made by my application from Fiddler

Tags: c#, http, fiddler

I have application which uses http to obtain data from my server like this:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestString);
req.Timeout = 200 * 1000;
req.Headers.Add(String.Format("deleteme: {0}", content));
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(resStream);
html = read.ReadToEnd();
```

Everything works fine, but how can I hide my requests from Fiddler (something similar to Wireshark)? I want to prevent users to see it.

Comment: This is very hard to archieve. You can try to connect to a proxy server, but the connection to the proxyserver will be visible in Wireshark/Fiddler. You cannot hide network traffic.

Comment: Well you can hide it from Fiddler, if you use custom proxy settings instead of relying on the machine settings. But then your application won't be able to access the network if the user has a legitimate reason to use a proxy (for instance, in a corporate environment). The only foolproof way is to use an HTTPS connection, **and** check the certificate (to make sure Fiddler or another software isn't doing a man in the middle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddler works by registering itself as the http proxy in Windows.

You can disable your application from using the default proxy by setting a specific proxy (like in the code below "no proxy") anywhere in your application before making web requests:

```
HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy();
```

Note that this will also prevent your application from using a configured proxy when one is set-up for legitimate reasons.

This will hide the requests from Fiddler or any other tool that traces web requests by registering itself as http proxy. This will not prevent tracing the request with other tools that operate on a different level in the stack (like Wireshark)

Security by obscurity does not really work. If you want to make it impossible to read the data transferred, use actual encryption.

Comment: This solution does **not** answer the question, in my humble opinion. (Even though OP thinks it might have) I'm not sure whether this is down to the unclear question text or a misunderstanding on either side, I'm however entirely focusing on the question title. This answer will **not** help you hide any traffic whatsoever. In fact, even a simple reroute/arp poisoning with the attacking machine running Fiddler or the like would be enough to "make it visible again". @NineBerry I would be very grateful if you could add this as warning. Let's not have new devs face the same problem and use this.

Comment: @FynnMazurkiewicz The OP specifically asks for hiding traffic from Fiddler. I have changed both the question title and my answer to emphasize this restriction.

Comment: That's still not enough. Fiddler is nothing more than a proxy and with a bit of routing magic, all this traffic can easily be intercepted. In fact, even on the machine running his app you could still make this traffic visible again, given you had a second network interface (on that same box) which would act as a a gateway. In other words, you haven't answered how to hide traffic from Fiddler, you just showed how to create proxy-unaware behaviour.